# Relationship between columns - awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file with a structure more or less like this:

**test:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 5 0 0
6 4 5 0 0
7 8 9 10 11
8 10 11 0 0
12 10 11 0 0
13 10 11 0 0
14 2 3 4 5
15 10 11 0 0
16 2 3 4 5
17 2 3 4 5
```

What I want is to get the first column when the 4th and the 5th are in the 2nd and 3rd, but the 2nd does not appear in the 2nd of the current line. It's a bit confusing, but it'd be like this:

```
1 6
7 12
7 13
7 15
14 6
16 6
17 6
```

I believe I'm almost there using this code:

```
cat test | awk 'NR==FNR {{a[$4" "$5]=a[$4" "$5]" "$1};next} $2" "$3 in a {print a[$2" "$3],$1}' - test
```

But the output that I get is:

```
1 14 16 17 2
1 14 16 17 6
7 8
7 12
7 13
7 15
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: To me, your statement *first column when the 4th and the 5th are in the 2nd and 3rd, but the 2nd does not appear in the 2nd of the current line.*  is totally confusing, and like the old joke "who's on first". Could you please explain by illustration or rewrite your explanation ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I think a good way to explain this problem is to consider that `test` has the following columns: `ID FATHER MOTHER GRANDFATHER GRANDMOTHER`. 
What I'm trying to get is the uncles (full sibs of the father) of each ID. Would that make sense?

Comment: Why isn't your first line of output `1 2` since the second line of input fulfills the requirement *first column where col 2 and col three equals a previous col 4 and col 5*? Your desired output is just not understandable given any text description you have given.

Comment: Hi @dawg. You are right, but 2 would be the father of the ID 1. That's why I don't want it there in the output. My idea is to just keep the uncles.

Comment: @godines I think I undersand the requirement but cannot immediately see a simple awk procedure, unless you do the heavy lifting in an END{} block... The approach would be build an array of arrays in the main block with indexes [r][c] where r is the line number and c the column number. In END you would make a nested loop with counters i and j for the row index of each pairwise combination of rows. In END you would compute `if([i][4]==[j][2] && [i][5]==[j]3 && [i][1]!=[j][1]) print [i][1]$1 print [j][1]$1`

Comment: Aha. So first, get the numbers in 4th and 5th column for line 1 (4 and 5). Then the 1st no. (4) must be in the 2nd column and 5th no. (5) in 3rd column in next line. Repeats.

Comment: @Darkman I think that's right. that's the interpretation I'd taken from the q

Comment: But where is the `7 8`?

Comment: @Darkman I thought 7 and 8 too but 8 is field 2 of 7 so doesn't count

Comment: ```6``` is uncle of ```14 16 17```. That's why I added them there.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions and add all clarification or additional information from your comments to your question. With the description of the columns as "ID FATHER MOTHER GRANDFATHER GRANDMOTHER", aren't the columns "GRANDFATHER GRANDMOTHER" redundant? (And every ID should normally have two grandfathers and two gandmothers.)

Answer (score 3):

(elaborating on my comment)

This `awk` procedure uses the main action block to build a 2-d array representing the input table. The `END` block then makes pair-wise comparisons for each row against all others. The logic looks for rows where the 4th and 5th entry in one row match the 2nd and 3rd entry of the other but excludes rows if the second entry holds the first entry of the row it's being compared to:

(input data is from file named `data.txt`)

```
awk ' 
{
     for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++) {
          table[NR, col] = $col;}
}

END {

  for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) {
  for(j=1; j<=FNR; j++) {
  
    if (table[i,4]==table[j,2] && table[i,5]==table[j,3] && table[i,2]!=table[j,1]) {
    print table[i,1]" "table[j,1];}

  }}

}

' data.txt
```

Output:

```
1 6
7 12
7 13
7 15
14 6
16 6
17 6
```

Comment: I'll investigate. I'd always assumed awk used the comma in the reference (i.e. the real index is "1,1", which would make sense given they're all associative and indexed numbers are pretty much meaningless). Nonetheless, what you say makes sense so I'll look into it. I've not previously encountered a problem with many-lined files although, like in this case, there might have to be coincidences for any issue to become apparent. Agreed, gawk solves many problems we don't realise exist in awk. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I just ran some tests in Terminal on my Mac. I read a table like the main block in my answer and tried the following (results in bracket) `print table[11]` (nothing printed); `print table[1,1]` (1 printed, as expected); then I set `table[11]="eleven"` and tried `print table[11]` (eleven printed as expected); `print table[1,1]` (1 printed as expected); more interesting... `print table['11']` (eleven printed); `print table['1,1']` (1 printed as expected). So far no ambiguity. I'll run some tests on your example when I've understood what you're suggesting.

Comment: If I've understood your example properly, all your example shows is that the keys print equivalently. I am fairly sure the indexes [1,1] and [11] are unambigous when used to reference values assigned to them.

Comment: To confused readers, my comments here relate to a now deleted comment pointing out (correctly) that the key values / index of awk arrays (when printed using `for key in array` ) don't distinguish between 11 and 1,1. In practice this oddity seems to be irrelevant as, (see my tests my 2nd comment  here) awk correctly uses the values assigned to [1,1] and [11] unambiguously.

Comment: The syntax `array[$1,$2]` is shorthand for `array[$1 SUBSEP $2]` so that the subscript is the string formed by `$1` and `$2` separated by whatever character is in `SUBSEP`. The default is the non-printing character of `\037` but could be anything. More [HERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html)

Comment: @dawg thanks, interesting.

Comment: This is the reason that `[1,1]` and `[11]` are unambiguously different.

Comment: @dawg that makes sense. I think the discussion (half now deleted) was provoked by the misunderstanding that "," was the actual separator. Using an 'invisible' separator is ingenious. A, W, and K were very smart guys.